# Where to place 'Type' specific functions whilst using a generic repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository

I'm wondering where the best place to put Type specific functions is when using a generic repository pattern.

My generic `Repository<T>` has methods for things like GetMany() etc, but where is the most sensible location to place functions specific to a Type?

A simple example would be, say I have a 'User' type and I want a function, which instead of bringing back the firstname / lastname of the user and requiring me to glue them together when the object set is returned, could return `FirstName + " " + LastName` as '`Username`'.

The previous non repository pattern implementation I've inherited used partial classes on the EF types to provide these extension methods, but I'm a little unsure where to move these type of functions to when using the respository.

Any ideas would be a big help,

Cheers,

Doug

Comment: Why are you using a generic repository if you need specific implementations?

Comment: You can glue then in LINQ `Select` method: `from p in repository.GetMany<User> select new { UserName = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName };

Comment: @alexn because 90% of the time the generic repository will cater for the situations we've encountered and it saves the repition for the basic functions like 'add' etc which don't seem well placed in a seperate implementation for the 90 or so entity types we have.

Comment: @KarelFrajtak Yes, this is one option, but it requires doing this each time I want to perform the operation, say I want to use the 'Username' field on 20 forms, it seems like there might/should be a better way to do this.

Comment: In that case subclass (as suggested in marked answer) and create reusable method.

Comment: @KarelFrajtak Yeah, as you say, this seems to be the most sensible way round things here, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below link explains how to specify  selection, instead of widening the contract of generic repository, the common technique is to subclass the generic repository to implement a specific repository

[EF POCO](http://huyrua.wordpress.com/2010/07/13/entity-framework-4-poco-repository-and-specification-pattern/)

```
 public class CustomerRepository : GenericRepository<Customer>, ICustomerRepository
{
    public CustomerRepository(ObjectContext context) : base(context) { }

    public IList<Customer> NewlySubscribed()
    {
        var lastMonth = DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(-1);

        return GetQuery().Where(c => c.Inserted >= lastMonth)
        .ToList();
    }

    public Customer FindByName(string firstname, string lastname)
    {
        return GetQuery().Where(c => c.Firstname == firstname && c.Lastname == lastname).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

you can add your function as the one used for NewlySubscribed()

Comment: Thanks @SShebly, this method works as we'd want and gives us a nice way to package up our type specific operations whilst retaining the flexiblity of a generic repository.

Answer (score 3):

I have created something similar, but all my type specific stuff is in sub classes that derive from `Repository<T>`. Generic stuff should remain generic. Type specific stuff becomes a typed repo.